# How to change language from ui from login page redirected automatically by cookie asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have set up automatic redirection to login page when unauthenticated in `Startup`:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
   options.LoginPath = "/Authentication";
   options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

And I have set up form for language changing taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-the-culture-programmatically.

How to make changing language on login page when unauthenticated?

Comment: You could try set cookies like:Response.Cookies.Append(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName, CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture("zh")))

Comment: I have set it up already, it wouldn't translate others page then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had set up an authentication requirement for all controllers, and the action, which changed the language, was in non-anonymous controller. I had to prepend this action with `[AllowAnonymous]` to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I teseted serval times for what may cause ASP.NET Core Localization not working

Besides the filepath and Name has been mentioned in official document.
The project file folder Name must be the same with your Namespace name,or the resource file may not be recognized.

The failed result:

[image]

The success result:
[image]

And some packages may needed:
[image]

And the success result accroding to my comment:
[image]
[image]
[image]